# get the last 3 characters with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

> Pro-King Construction Ltd.:AF28118-CGY - Starbucks

and I am trying to get the `CGY` with a regex

This one:

```
/(?<=:)(.*?)(?=-)/g
```

gets `AF28118`

This one:

```
/(?<=-)[^\s]+/g
```

gets the `CGY` but also the `King` because it is after the `-`

this one:

```
/(?<=:)[^\s]+/g
```

gets `AF28118-CGY`

Does anyone know how can I get just the `CGY`?

Comment: It is not clear why you want to use RegEx, and not just get the last 3 letters from the string with `text.substr(text.length - 3);`, according to your question's title.

Comment: try this `-(\w+)?\s*-`

Comment: You don't use lookbehinds with JS.

Comment: you could always do `string.split(':')[1]` and then use the second regex - the word King will not be included because it'll be in `string.split(':')[0]`

Comment: Try `-([A-Z]+)(?= *-)`

Comment: Provided your browser supports lookbehind assertions, you may use: [`(?<=-)[^\s-]+(?=\s*-)`](https://regex101.com/r/LwBT52/1/)

Comment: Try this... `[a0-z9]{3}$`

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD NOT use lookbehinds in JS for the reason that not all major browsers support it YET. If you are trying to extract `CGY` you are in need of capturing groups. Almost all cases that include lookarounds could be done with use of capturing groups:

```js
var str = `Pro-King Construction Ltd.:AF28118-CGY - Starbucks`;
console.log(str.match(/-([A-Z]+)( *-)/)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just split the string on "-" (assuming the format of all other strings will be the same) and then just grab the item that you are looking for? In your case the code would look something like the following

`str_to_extract = "Pro-King Construction Ltd.:AF28118-CGY - Starbucks"
final_str = str_to_extract.split("-")[2].strip()`

final_str should now be CGY which is what you wanted

Hope this helps :)